# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returning wrong date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Quick question.

I have a string date: example `var dateString = "17-02-2015"`

I use:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

var newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

And I get the output: `2015-01-16 23:02:00 +0000`

Why am I missing a day? Is it because of the time zone? (I am at +1, and in the date the timezone is 0?).

I also tryed setting the time zone:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

But no success.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the UTC time and it is correct considering the fact that your LocalTime is 1+

```
var dateString = "17-02-2015"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

var newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!

println(newDate.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())!)
```

Comment: Thats funny, that when i set the Locale in the dateFormatter, nothing happens, but when I output with the descriptionWIthLocale(...) it works perfectly! Thank you.