# Convert Specific Date String to Swift 3 Date While Adjusting for TimeZone

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3, nsdate

I know how to convert a datestring in this format (`2016-11-02 05:45:05.000000`) to a date in Swift3 but I can't figure out why the time that spits back out from the print command is off from the original by so much? **From reading it might be setting it to a different timezone, but if that is the case how do I reset it back to the original time?**

It incorrectly looks like this below for the sample time I gave above.  Notice it's off by many hours.

```
2016-11-02 12:45:05 +0000
```

Here is my code below and the image showing the console print commands.

```
let dateString : String       = task["created"]!.asDictionary!["date"]!.asString!

                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"

                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

                print(name)
                print("\(id)")
                print(desc)
                print(dateString)
                print(date!)
```

[image]

Please refer to the image.

Comment: "Working With Fixed Format Date Representations" https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdateformatter

Comment: Please let me know why negative vote so I can fix the question, I put a lot more effort into this question this time.  I feel this is a legitimate issue a lot of users would have.

Comment: I don't get what to look for in the link you provided, can you elaborate, this is complicated because of the .000000 at the end, I'm unclear how to work with it actually.  I can't tell if its all microseconds or if only 4 digits are microseconds and the other 00's are something else?? Also Alexander Mornchliov if you downvoted, this question is vastly different from the other and I deleted that question since it did indeed have a duplicate answer.  I do not see a duplicate in this case.

Comment: I down voted because 1) this issue is well documented, 2) you haven't demonstrated any effort. Clearly it's a timezone related issue. What have you tried?

Comment: I would argue while its possible its documented, that documentation didn't solve my issue.  Assuming its a timezone issue, how do I solve that? that was my entire question in the first place.  I don't know where to find that information.  I demonstrated a lot of effort! most people don't even post a screenshot...

Comment: That screen shot provides no additional information over the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128113/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-joseph-astrahan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557321/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returning-wrong-date: The formatter interprets the string in your local time zone, and printing a `Date` always uses UTC. You are in the GMT+7 zone, aren't you?

Comment: that link is similar but its not in swift 3, that question could possibly be updated though? In anycase, found the answer to the question and appreciate the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the timezone:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: Note that this should only be done if the string represents UTC time. If the string represents local time then this solution is wrong.